# JS files not found (404)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, http-status-code-404

I'm running the application locally and it works fine.  When I uploaded it to my hosting account I started getting 404 errors on JS

It's happening in both Chrome and Firefox.

[Chrome Inspect Element Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaE4R.png)

[The directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GioW0.png)

The files are located in the designated location and the code is at the bottom of the page so they shouldn't be getting accessed before they're loaded.

```html
 
<script src="libs/bootstrap-switch-master/docs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap-toggle-master/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-auto-validate/dist/jcs-auto-validate.min.js" ></script>
<script src="libs/ladda/dist/spin.min.js" ></script>
<script src="libs/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js" ></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ladda/dist/angular-ladda.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/clipboard.js-master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery-color-master/jquery.color.js"></script>

<script src="main.js" ></script>

</body >
</html >
```

Comment: Here is the link:  http://ztsales.com/support-wizard/

Comment: The files either aren't in the directory you think they are (have you looked?), or they haven't even been uploaded. Only you can know for sure where those files are, and whether they're accessible. If you browse into `libs` do you then see additional directories like `angular`? And if you go into those additional directories do you see the files in question?

Comment: You should hide all your directory from public access... http://ztsales.com/support-wizard/libs/

Comment: Yes, they are there.  It was running perfectly fine on a local Tomcat.

Comment: if you put directly in your browser (for example): http://ztsales.com/support-wizard/libs/angular/angular.min.js They didn't found... If you put: http://ztsales.com/support-wizard/libs you didn't found the directory angular...

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome Developer Tools (F12 in Google Chrome), if you go to the sources tab you can see the content (css and js) that is on the page. It appears that some of your files are missing and some of the directories are incorrect.

It looks like with some of the content you assumed that support-wizard was the root directory when it isn't.

For example, some of your sources should be:

```
/support-wizard/libs/ladda/dist/spin.min.js
/support-wizard/libs/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js
/support-wizard/libs/bootstrap-toggle-master/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css
```

[image]

If you try going to each page it should load (ie: ztsales.com/support-wizard/libs/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js)

Comment: If I add that to the PATHs, it still doesn't load them.

Comment: It fixed some of them, if you see the spin.min.js and ladda.min.js are now loaded. You need to check the paths of the other ones as well and see what is missing.  Look at the sources tab in Chrome Developer Tools it is very useful. If you try going to each page it should load (ie: http://ztsales.com/support-wizard/libs/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js)

Comment: Thats not the problem... The problem is that the file doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Some of them seem to be missing, but some of them seem to have the wrong directory like the ones that I posted

Comment: They're definitely there in cpanel.  Adding pics to the next post.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

It was a permissions issue. The PATHs were right but the problematic directories and files didn't have execute permissions.

EDIT(zpert): Make sure directory permissions are 755, which means:

- Owner: Read, Write, Execute
- Group: Read, Execute
- Public: Read, Execute

Comment: how you given the permission can give you show me. I also facing same issue. Thank You.

Comment: @s.k.Soni run in terminal: `chmod 755 your/directory`